# Add a click event to css background image

Tags: javascript, css

I have a css that displays an image in the left bottom corner:

```
body {
    background-image: url(../img.png);
    background-size: 5%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 3% 95%;
}
```

I want to be able to open a web page in the new tab once clicking on that image. Is there any way to achieve that with javscript?

In that case I am using a [revealjs](https://revealjs.com) so the general structure looks like

```
<body>
        <div class="reveal">
            <div class="slides">
                <section>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you also share your html pls

Comment: You can't assign a click event to a background image. You can create an element and then assign an event listener to it.

Comment: Click events happen on HTML elements, not CSS styles.  What element will the user be clicking on?  You could possibly listen on the whole body/document/window/whatever and get the mouse coordinates on the click event and then do some math to see if the click happened within the bounds that you would expect this image to be, likely based on window size.  Sounds like a lot of work and fine tuning and high potential for false results though.

Comment: @David seems like I do need to add an html element say `div` and just assign my background image to that so then I able to add a click event.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the CSS on the body tag and include a image tag into the HTML.

```css
.img 
{
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<html> 
   <body>   
      <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp">
          <img class="img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/49/LACMTA_Square_Orange_Line.svg" alt="image at bottom">
      </a>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a div element that sits in the bottom left, that is wrapped in a  element that will link you to the "href" specified.

You cannot assign a link to background image, but you can to an element that has the background of your choosing.

Hope this helps :)

HTML:

```
<a href="http://google.com">
  <div id="corner-img"></div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
#corner-img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 2px;
}
```

Comment: You don't need `<div>` as background can be added to `<a>` directly.

Comment: Sure it can be, I personally prefer placing a div inside the element :)

Comment: Extraneous elements spoil your code =)) It's not a question of personal preferences, but code quality.